# Method is not being added to Prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I have js file which I am using to learn javascript. However when I run concatAll, it says :

```
Uncaught TypeError: movieLists.map(...).concatAll is not a function
```

Js File:

```
console.log(tryFun());

Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        results.push(subArray);
    });

    return results;
};



function tryFun() {
    var movieLists = [
        {
            name: "New Releases",
            videos: [
                {
                    "id": 70111470,
                    "title": "Die Hard",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 4.0,
                    "bookmark": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 654356453,
                    "title": "Bad Boys",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 5.0,
                    "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Dramas",
            videos: [
                {
                    "id": 65432445,
                    "title": "The Chamber",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 4.0,
                    "bookmark": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 675465,
                    "title": "Fracture",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 5.0,
                    "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

return movieLists.map(movieList=>
        movieList.videos.map(video=>video.id))
.concatAll();
}
```

Looks like I am missing some trick here.Thanks for looking into this.Should Javascript not add the function on its prototype which is defined at the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `tryFun` before `concatAll` has been added. Add the method to the prototype *before* calling `tryFun`:

```js
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        results.push(subArray);
    });

    return results;
};

console.log(tryFun());


function tryFun() {
    var movieLists = [
        {
            name: "New Releases",
            videos: [
                {
                    "id": 70111470,
                    "title": "Die Hard",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 4.0,
                    "bookmark": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 654356453,
                    "title": "Bad Boys",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 5.0,
                    "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: "Dramas",
            videos: [
                {
                    "id": 65432445,
                    "title": "The Chamber",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 4.0,
                    "bookmark": []
                },
                {
                    "id": 675465,
                    "title": "Fracture",
                    "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture.jpg",
                    "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
                    "rating": 5.0,
                    "bookmark": [{ id: 432534, time: 65876586 }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

return movieLists.map(movieList=>
        movieList.videos.map(video=>video.id))
.concatAll();
}
```

But mutating the built-in objects is *very* bad practice - it would be better to call a standalone function, or use your own wrapper.

Comment: However should not Hoisting be taking care of it? I mean when first pass of compilation happens, javascript will come to know that a new method is added to the prototype and when this new method is invoked, it should search for it? Looks like there is a gap in my understanding

Comment: Only functions *declarations* are hoisted (eg `function abc() { }`). Function *expressions*, where you explicitly assign a function to a variable or to a property of something, are not hoisted. (eg `obj.x = function() { ...` and `someClass.prototype.customMethod = function(){ ...` are both using function expressions rather than function declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Ohh got it ! Its program flow, concatAll was never added.Just moving the call helps:

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        results.push(subArray);
    });

    return results;
};

console.log(tryFun());
```

Comment: However  should not Hoisting be taking care of it? I mean when first pass of compilation happens, javascript will come to know that a new method is added to the prototype and when this new method is invoked, it should search for it? Looks like there is a gap in my understanding .

Comment: No, assignments are never hoisted. Only declarations.

Comment: Ohh yes it was not at top of my head ! Thanks Train !

Answer (score 1):

Generally related to what you're trying to implement, you can pretty easily get by without a `.concatAll()` function, since `.concat()` is variadic and will flatten Arrays automatically.

So with "spread syntax", you can do this:

```
return [].concat(...movieLists.map(
    movieList => movieList.videos.map(video => video.id))
);
```

---

Here's a live demo:

```js
console.log(tryFun());

function tryFun() {
  var movieLists = [{
      name: "New Releases",
      videos: [{
          "id": 70111470,
          "title": "Die Hard",
          "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/DieHard.jpg",
          "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
          "rating": 4.0,
          "bookmark": []
        },
        {
          "id": 654356453,
          "title": "Bad Boys",
          "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/BadBoys.jpg",
          "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
          "rating": 5.0,
          "bookmark": [{
            id: 432534,
            time: 65876586
          }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Dramas",
      videos: [{
          "id": 65432445,
          "title": "The Chamber",
          "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/TheChamber.jpg",
          "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
          "rating": 4.0,
          "bookmark": []
        },
        {
          "id": 675465,
          "title": "Fracture",
          "boxart": "http://cdn-0.nflximg.com/images/2891/Fracture.jpg",
          "uri": "http://api.netflix.com/catalog/titles/movies/70111470",
          "rating": 5.0,
          "bookmark": [{
            id: 432534,
            time: 65876586
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  return [].concat(...movieLists.map(
      movieList => movieList.videos.map(video => video.id))
  );
}
```

Or you could use `.reduce()` and put the `.concat()` in the callback.

```
  return movieLists.reduce(
      (res, movieList) => res.concat(...movieList.videos.map(video => video.id))
  , []);
```

Comment: perfect ! No need for my home grown solution !Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Even more simple try below code.

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        results.push.apply(results, subArray);
    });

    return results;
};
console.log(tryFun());
```